Getting a workspace's namespace via GeoServer REST API
I have set up a workspace named "foo" and set its namespace to "bar".
How can I find out its namespace setting via the REST API? The information is not included in a call to /workspaces/foo nor in the /namespaces/:
$ curl -u "admin:geoserver" -X GET "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/foo" | json_pp

{
   "workspace" : {
      "coverageStores" : "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/foo/coveragestores.json",
      "dataStores" : "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/foo/datastores.json",
      "dateCreated" : "2024-04-25 08:47:10.879 UTC",
      "dateModified" : "2024-04-25 08:51:56.6 UTC",
      "isolated" : true,
      "name" : "foo",
      "wmsStores" : "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/foo/wmsstores.json",
      "wmtsStores" : "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/foo/wmtsstores.json"
   }
}

$ curl -u "admin:geoserver" -X GET "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces/" | json_pp

{
   "namespaces" : {
      "namespace" : [
         {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces/default.json",
            "name" : "default"
         },
         {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces/foo.json",
            "name" : "foo"
         }
      ]
   }
}


There is a difference between namespace and namespace URI. In the GUI there is a field for the namespace URI which is what I am after:

The namespace itself is using the workspace's name so this query gives me the URI:
curl -u "admin:geoserver" -X GET "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces/foo" | json_pp

{
   "namespace" : {
      "isolated" : false,
      "prefix" : "foo",
      "uri" : "bar"
   }
}

